# Fastest Way - Iterate List items and set them selected

Tags: c#, performance, listbox, iteration, selecteditem

Currently i got a listbox with list of workers and another array containing list of names of the workers who are selected in the listbox. How well will the below code perform , i am looking for improvements or better way to do this.

```
    string[] keys = tempTaskRecord.GetWorkers().AllKeys;
    foreach (ListItem assignedEmployee in lstWorkers.Items)
    {
        foreach (string employeeName in keys)
        {
            assignedEmployee.Selected = assignedEmployee.Text.Equals(employeeName);
        }
    }
```

#### Edit Code

```
    string[] keys = tempTaskRecord.GetWorkers().AllKeys;
    foreach (ListItem assignedEmployee in lstWorkers.Items)
    {
        foreach (string employeeName in keys)
        {
            if (!assignedEmployee.Text.Equals(employeeName)) continue;
            assignedEmployee.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

**Where,**

GetWorkers() return a `NameValueCollection`.

lstWorkers is the `ListBox` with list items of all employees.

Working in .NET 2.0 (No Linq sorry :) )

Comment: could you give us the records count - keys.length and lstWorkers.Items.Count?

Comment: @Dmitry yup listbox count are multiple of hundreds unto 1K ( i have search box too), keys.length is well no limit right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The code you posted won't actually work - only the last employee in the list will be selected.
You should reverse the order of your for-loops to fix this.</s> (Fixed in your edited code).

I would do something like this:

```
    lstWorkers.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ListItem assignedEmployee in lstWorkers.Items)
    {
        assignedEmployee.Selected = keys.Contains(assignedEmployee.Text);
    }
    lstWorkers.EndUpdate();
```

And if you have a lot of selected employees, consider converting `keys` to a hashset or similar.

**Edit:** Actually, you could use your `NameValueCollection` instead of the keys array.

```
    var selected = tempTaskRecord.GetWorkers();
    lstWorkers.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ListItem assignedEmployee in lstWorkers.Items)
    {
        assignedEmployee.Selected = (selected.Values(assignedEmployee.Text) != null);
    }
    lstWorkers.EndUpdate();
```

`selected.Values()` is O(1) if you have one worker per key according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so this approach is O(n).

Comment: the edit code works now & selects the assigned workers. I still don't know if this would be as fast as user676571 answer

Comment: I believe @user676571 's code would be similar, except mine doesn't require the first loop through `keys`. You could always benchmark it :)

Comment: I think this would be faster. Any slight lookup improvement using the dictionary will be more than outweighed by the dictionary construction.

Comment: honestly, I don't see how that operation could be O(1)

Comment: @user676571: Hashes are O(1) as stated in the docs. I agree there could be more than one entry in each hash bucket, but it's nearer to O(1) than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

A better way:

```
Dictionary<string, object> assignedOnes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(var key in keys)
  assignedOnes[key] = null;

foreach (ListItem assignedEmployee in lstWorkers.Items)
  assignedEmployee.Selected = assignedOnes.ContainsKey(assignedEmployee.Text);
```

This would reduce complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log n) .

**Edit**

Upon further checking, it seems that dictionary [also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) 'approaches' O(1), meaning that presented algorithm would also be O(n)